# Jquery Datatables Adjust the size of table to fit the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm creating an app with jQuery Datatables, and I want the tables to look the same no matter what type of resolution the pc have.
 
 For example In 1920x1366 the tables fits the page perfectly, but on the 1366x768 I have to scroll horizontally and vertically to see the other columns, but I just want the tables to be smaller. 
 
How can I do this? Use some kind of container or a function in datatables?

Greetings, Rafał.

Comment: Try setting width of table to 100%

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    table {
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for support, this is a good solution, but when the window is smaller it didn't fit the size of the font and the table is a little bit not quite readable, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Table tag you use for your datatable to table width=100% .
This needs to be done directly in the html tag, not in the css as described here:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/flexible_width.html

Comment: Thanks for support, unfortunately this was set at the beginning and I don't know why the datatables doesn't fit to the screen.